# Stack Overflow joined date format different in jobs CV PDF

Tags: bug, status-completed, developer-story, traditional-view

The developer story when rendered as a PDF has an entry under "Projects & Interests" for when I joined Stack Overflow. Its date format is "YYYY/MM" which is different to all other dates.

[image]

I assume the format should be made consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for catching this! Your pdf export should now have consistent date formats :).

Comment: Just for completeness - what format was chosen in the end?

Comment: @JonClements the format for the pdf export is "MMM yyyy"